# Geodjango Querying geometry returns pointer instead of geometry

Tags: python, django, geometry, geodjango, centroid

I am trying to get a single MultiPolygon geometry in a Queryset from this model:

```
class local_administrative_unit(models.Model):
    lau_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    lau_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    adm_level_2 = models.ForeignKey('administrative_level_2', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    geom = models.MultiPolygonField(srid=4326)
```

trying it this way in the Django shell:

```
local_administrative_unit.objects.get(lau_id=1).geom
```

which returned:

```
<MultiPolygon object at 0x7fb12af0ab10>
```

when I pass this to the *Centroid* function, it does not what I was looking for:

```
Centroid(Value(<MultiPolygon object at 0x7fb12af0ac90>))
```

Can you please tell me how I get the actual geometry to use it afterwards - for example for calculating the Centroid of that polygon? Looks like I am getting a pointer to what I am looking for instead of the actual thing.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meanwhile I found what i missed. It is basically all explained in the [GeoDjango Tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/gis/tutorial/#lazy-geometries) which i appearently overlooked before. GeoDjango creates a *GEOSGeometry* object when the geometry is first accessed on which certain properties then can be used to do stuff.
In the above case this means:

```
foo = local_administrative_unit.objects.get(lau_id=1).geom
print(foo)
<MultiPolygon object at 0x7fb12af0ab10>
```

*foo* holds the geometry object as the one in the initial example, to get the centroid in a generally useable form we can just use some properties:

```
bar = foo.centroid
bar.wkt
```

This will calculate the centroid and return it then in well-known text.